# Domain mapping when performing dimensionality reduction

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

Consider the problem of performing dimensionality reduction from a vector space $V_{1}$ of dimension M to another one, $V_{2}$, of dimension N, where N<M.

Is there a technique or theory which guides how to map domain boundaries from $V_{1}$ to $V_{2}$?

For example, say that the data in $V_{1}$ must satisfy min and max constraints in each dimension. Hence the domain will result in some "cuboid" shape, consisting of $2^{M}$ corners. How this domain will be mapped in $V_{2}$?